# LLVM coverage confused by if-constexpr

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++, if-constexpr, llvm-cov

I have encountered a weird problem with LLVM coverage when using constant expressions in an `if-statement`:

```
template<typename T>
int foo(const T &val)
{
    int idx = 0;

    if constexpr(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int)
    {
        memcpy(&idx, &v, sizeof(T));
    }
    else
    {
        //store val and assign its index to idx
    }

    return idx;
}
```

The instantiations executed:

```
int idx1 = foo<int>(10);
int idx2 = foo<long long>(10);
int idx3 = foo<std::string>(std::string("Hello"));
int idx4 = foo<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5});
```

In none of these is the `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int)` ever shown as executed. And yet in the first case instantiation (`int`) the body of the first `if` is indeed executed as it should. In none other it is shown as executed.

Relevant part of the compilation command line:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -pipe -fexceptions -fvisibility=default -fPIC -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -I(...) -std=c++17 -o test.o -c test.cpp
```

Relevant part of the linker command line:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -Wl,-m,elf_x86_64,-rpath,/home/michael/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib -L/home/michael/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -o testd test.o -lpthread -fuse-ld=lld
```

When the condition is extracted to its own fucnction both `int` and `long long` instantiations are shown correctly in the coverage as executing the `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int)` part. What might be causing such behaviour and how to solve it? Is it a bug in the Clang/LLVM cov?

Any ideas?

EDIT: This seems to be a known bug in LLVM (not clear yet if LLVM-cov or Clang though):

https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36086

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=845575

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int)` should be executed at compile-time in your code, so chances are, compilation is not profiled for coverage.

Next, of those three types only `long long` looks `trivially_copyable`, but its size is (highly likely) more than that of `int`, so then-clause is not executed for them, nor even compiled. Since everything happens inside a templated function, the non-executed branch is not compiled.

Comment: The first point is valid. The second is misunderstanding. The `else` is correctly shown as either executed or not, that is not the issue. The issue is second condition of the if statement not showing as executed at all. And `int` also satisfies the condition, not just `long long`.

Comment: Yes, int is the only type that satisfies the RHS operand of && in `if constexpr`'s condition. Can you be more specific in what extracted where and what executed when?

Comment: The expectation is that `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int)` condition would be executed for `int` and `long long` yet it does not show as executed for none of the 4 specializations despite the `memcpy(&idx, &v, sizeof(T));` being executed once. I understand that the condition is `contexpr` and thus compile time but LLVM-cov should understand that I would expect (and probably ignore it in the coverage).